# WordPress - wp_ajax_ 400 bad request

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm having a bat time trying to make work wp ajax.

I have added this action inside my plugin code construct

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_submit_support_ticket', [$this, 'submit_support_ticket']);
```

and to manage the ajax call I have created this method

```php
    public function submit_support_ticket()
    {

        $request_type = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['reqType'] );
        $request_issuer = sanitize_email( $_POST['issuerEmail'] );
        $request_message = sanitize_textarea_field( $_POST['reqMessage'] );

        var_dump( $request_type, $request_issuer, $request_message );

        switch( $request_type ){
            case '1':
                $subject = '...';
                break;
            case '2':
                $subject = '...';
                break;
            case '3':
                $subject = '...';
                break;
            case '4':
                $subject = '...';
                break;
        }

        //wp_mail( $to:string|array, $subject:string, $message:string, $headers:string|array, $attachments:string|array )
        $to = 'user@example.com';
        $headers[] = 'From: Sistema Ticketing WordPress <no-reply@example.com>';
        $headers[] = 'Cc: User <user@example.com>';
        $headers[] = 'Cc: User <user@example.com>';
        $headers[] = 'Cc: User <user@example.com>';

        if( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $request_message, $headers ) ){
            return [
                'status' => 'success',
                'message' => '...'
            ];
        } else {
            return [
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => '...'
            ];
        }
    }
```

I've also created a dedicated javascript file that will hold the logics to send the ajax post request

```
const siteURL = window.location.origin
const requestType = document.getElementById('request-type');
const issuerEmail = document.getElementById('issuer-email');
const requestMessage = document.getElementById('request-message');
const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit-button');
const successMessage = document.getElementById('form-wrapper-success');
const errorMessage = document.getElementById('form-wrapper-error');

//
submitButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(siteURL, requestType.value, issuerEmail.value, requestMessage.value);
    fetch(ajaxurl, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
            action: 'submit_support_ticket',
            reqType: requestType.value,
            issuerEmail: issuerEmail.value,
            reqMessage: requestMessage.value
        }
    }).then( (res) =>  {
        console.log(res)
    }).catch( e => console.log(e) )  
});
```

I've done some test but everytime I will get a 400 bad request error from the server.
How I can fix this?

Comment: Did you try using json_enconde() in your php code?
https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-return-json-from-a-php-script.php#:~:text=Answer%3A%20Use%20the%20json_encode(),set%20the%20Content%2DType%20header.

Comment: no, didn't tried. In my php code I just need to get the dashboard widget data inserted from the user and send them using `wp_mail`

Comment: Ok, but you are sending a request that yields a result, your ajax call is not getting a proper html response because of your return statements. If you are not going to be using the result of the call in the response object of the ajax result, how do you intend to update your widget if you are not posting the page?

Comment: @ShiinZu I don't really need to have a response, I just created two messages that I will use in JS logic to show a success or error message.

Comment: Exactly my point if you are creating this message, that is the response and it needs to be formatted as a Json object so the javascript code can react accordingly. You are returning a couple of strings that javascript cannot interpret.

Comment: @ShiinZu WordPress will convert the response into a json by default, but the problem isn't the response message but the fact that the ajax request will not trigger the preposed function to send the email. The script seems work only from postman.